# Chef data bags (JSON): how to use one file with multiple items

Tags: json, chef-infra, chef-solo, databags

I'm trying to use only one file in my Data Bag to contain multiple items (specifically for the [users](https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/users) cookbook). All samples show isolated JSON objects. How do I store multiple ones in one file?

I've tried

```
{
  "id": "1"
},
{
  "id": "2"
}
```

and

```
[
    {
      "id": "1"
    },
    {
      "id": "2"
    }
]
```

and

```
{
  "id": "1"
}
{
  "id": "2"
}
```

I'm getting:

```
Net::HTTPFatalError: users_manage[xxxxx] (common::default line 76) had an error: Net::HTTPFatalError: 500 "Internal Server Error"
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http/response.rb:119:in `error!'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.8.1/lib/chef/http.rb:145:in `request'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.8.1/lib/chef/http.rb:110:in `get'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.8.1/lib/chef/search/query.rb:158:in `call_rest_service'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.8.1/lib/chef/search/query.rb:87:in `search'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.8.1/lib/chef/dsl/data_query.rb:39:in `search'
```

I'm using `chef-solo -z` with the chef-solo-search cookbook.

Can't I pass an array of items from one file?

Comment: Worth noting, there is no such thing as `chef-solo -z`. Either use `chef-client -z` or `chef-solo` + `chef-solo-search`. One or the other, not both.

Answer (score 0):

You do not store multiple items in one data bag file in Chef. Just specify it in separate files. This is, how Chef works.

Comment: Thank you Stephan. So if I have 500 users, I'll need to have 500 files in my "users" data bag ? No way around it ?

Comment: Not as far as I know.

Comment: Chef itself is an API and doesn't care about the files per se, but chef-zero uses them to form its database so for `chef-client -z` you do need them.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try something like:

`{
  "id": "users",
  "users": [
   { ... user 1 info ... },
   { ... user 2 info ... },
   { ... user 3 info ... },
    ...
  ]
}`

Comment: That would at least not be compatible with the _users_ cookbook. Sure you can squeeze all data into one item of a data bag, but that's just not how it's meant to be.

Comment: tried it anyway - seems it's can't parse the object:

`   NoMethodError
    -------------
    undefined method \`each' for nil:NilClass

    Cookbook Trace:
    ---------------
    /srv/chef/local-mode-cache/cache/cookbooks/users/providers/manage.rb:60:in \`block (2 levels) in class_from_file'
    /srv/chef/local-mode-cache/cache/cookbooks/users/providers/manage.rb:58:in \`block in class_from_file'
`